how come normal user cannot see nfs shares with df?
the Question: where is this officially documented?
cannot find it in eg.: https://linux.die.net/man/1/df
i have a suspicion that it is related to that the user doesn’t have UNIX level permission for those shares.
user@sles:~> df -h|grep -i foobar
user@sles:~> sudo df -h|grep -i foobar
1.2.3.4:/foobar  110G   40M  110G   1% /root/foobar
1.2.3.4:/foobar2  180G  106G   75G  59% /root/foobar2
user@sles:~>

but this can confuse people that just want to list ALL the mounted shares without root permission.

It's not just NFS.
The way df works, is that it needs to run stat(2) system call on every mount point to get its details. If the user doesn't have access to the directory that contains the mountpoint, stat doesn't work. In your case, /root doesn't have executable bit for others, so regular users cannot stat any directory located inside /root.
$ df /root/foobar
df: /root/foobat: Permission denied

$ ls /root/foobar
ls: cannot access '/root/foobar': Permission denied

You'll be able to see all mounts as the user by running the mount command, or if you want to only see NFS mounts, mount -t nfs. The mount command only shows you the mounts it finds in /proc/self/mountinfo without running stat on every mountpoint like df does.

I think you mean it runs statfs(2)
